# is_copy_constructible typetrait gives wrong answer

Tags: c++, type-traits

In the below code, `is_copy_constructible_v` returns true, but MainClass' copy constructor is marked as deleted.

Trying to call the copy constructor is be a compilation error.
So how come that `is_copy_constructible_v` does not see it?

```
class BaseClass {};

class MainClass : public BaseClass {
public:
    MainClass(MainClass&) = delete;

    MainClass(const BaseClass& rhs)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    MainClass first{{}};

    //This line will not compile because MainClass::MainClass(MainClass&) is a deleted function
    //MainClass second{first};

    auto mainclass_is_constructible = std::is_copy_constructible_v<MainClass>;

    //This assert fails because is_copy_constructible_v returns true
    static_assert((std::is_copy_constructible_v<MainClass>) == 0);
}
```

This was found from having unit tests for that check if a given class is copyable/movable.
They work fine, but not after adding the equivalent of `MainClass(const BaseClass& rhs)` in real code.

If instead we have `MainClass(const BaseClass& rhs, int value)`, then `is_copy_constructible_v` will work.

What would happen given an `std::vector<MainClass>`, if we also delete the move ctor/assignment? Won't the vector make use of `is_copy_constructible_v` to detect how to operate best, and receive a wrong answer?

Many thanks

Comment: You didn't delete `MainClass(MainClass const&)`.  That leaves a valid copy constructor available.

Comment: It is copyable. You can verify by doing: `MainClass second{static_cast<const MainClass&>(first)};` so it calls the copy constructor instead of the pass-by-reference constructor. Even doing: `const auto& temp = first; MainClass second{temp};` will work.

Comment: Indeed, it should have been `MainClass(const MainClass&)`. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MainClass` has a `MainClass::MainClass(const BaseClass& rhs)`, which makes constructing `MainClass` from a const lvalue possible, e.g.

```
const MainClass first{{}};

// This line will compile because MainClass::MainClass(const BaseClass& rhs) is usable
// a MainClass could be bound to const BaseClass&
MainClass second{first};
```

And [`std::is_copy_constructible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_copy_constructible) performs the check as:

> provides a member constant value equal to `std::is_constructible<T, const T&>::value`.

Note that it's checking whether `T` could be constructed from `const T&`, then it yields `true` for `MainClass`.

If you declare the copy constructor as:

```
MainClass(const MainClass&) = delete;
```

You'll get the result `false`.

> What would happen given an `std::vector<MainClass>`

It'll use the `MainClass::MainClass(const BaseClass& rhs)` (for `push_back` or reallocation etc). If it's not what you expect you have to reconsider the design.

Comment: Thank you very much, this question was from the failure to notify the missing const in `MainClass(MainClass&) = delete;` Now with `MainClass(const MainClass&) = delete;` it is of course working.